Geo locator giving error when added in project
Execution failed for task ':location:compileDebugKotlin'.

A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
Compilation error. See log for more details

After adding the Geo locator permission it is giving the above error.
Code snippet for pubspec.yaml

I have add this dependency and and then did the AGP upgrade but not able to get a proper solution.

You can try adding dependencies like pubspec.yaml
After that just try perform the above mentioned steps.

flutter clean
flutter pub get


Let me put and check it.

Wohoo it is working fine.!!!! Thanks!
